# JavaScript 2D Array Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working on a project where I need to add points to an array. Here is the code for creating and then trying to add an object to the array:

```
var points = [];
    points[0] = [];
    points[0][0] = 0; //x-coord
    points[0][1] = 0; //y-coord

points[points.length][0] = x; //Breaks on this line
points[points.length][1] = y;
```

The exact error I get is **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**. This code is run every time a button is pressed and the other values are already `ints` that are set. I thought that JavaScript allowed you to set values in arrays as you go?

Comment: I'd recommend using an array of objects instead: `points = []; points[0] = {x: 0, y: 0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last array index is `points.length - 1`. Now you are addressing an element past the end of array (which is `undefined`) and trying to assign its "0" property a value of `x`. Setting properties on `undefined` is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I posted, I realize I was initializing the second array and had to write a function to instantiate the inner arrays. Thanks for the prompt answer though!

Answer (score 1):

your array contains:

```
var points = [
    [0,0]
]
```

However

```
points[points.length]
//is
points[1]
```

which does not exist. you must create the array first, before you actually add stuff to it

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zqrGe/1/)

```
var length = points.length;  //cache value, since length is "live"
points[length] = [];         //using the cached length, create new array
points[length][0] = x;       //add values
points[length][1] = y;
```